# Quantitative Perron formula with weights

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory

For $\kappa >1$ and $t,X\geq 1$ $$\sum _{n\leq X}a_n=\frac {1}{2\pi i}\int _{\kappa \pm iT}\frac {\mathcal F(s)X^sds}{s}+\mathcal O\left (x^\kappa \sum _{=1}^\infty \frac {1}{n^\kappa (1+T|\log (X/n)|)}\right )$$ where $a_n\ll 1$ and $$\mathcal F(s)=\sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac {a_n}{n^s}.$$ This is a quantitative version of Perron's formula - the above is taken from Page 132 of Tenenbaum's *Introduction to Probabilistic Number Theory*.

On page 134, display (11), we have a qualitative version of Perron wit the first Cesaro weight $$\sum _{n\leq X}a_n(X-n)=\frac {1}{2\pi i}\int _{\kappa \pm i\infty }\frac {\mathcal F(s)X^{s+1}ds}{s(s+1)}.$$

Is there anywhere a quantative version of this weighted version?  I can prove it, but surely it must already be somewhere.

Comment: It’s not in Chapter 5 of Montgomery-Vaughan?

Comment: only the qualitative result :(

Comment: Hmmm. I don't know where else you could hope to find it. I would just prove it from scratch (and in an analytic number theory paper, I would be very terse, since it's essentially classical).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $|a_n|\ll 1$ and $c>1$, then

$\displaystyle\sum_{n\leq x}(x-n)a_n = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{c-iT}^{c+iT}\mathcal{F}(s)\frac{x^{s+1}}{s(s+1)}ds+O\Big(\frac{x^{c+1}(\log x)^2}{T^2}\Big)$.

A detailed proof can be found in Murty's "Problems in Analytic Number Theory", solution to Problem 4.1.8.

Comment: $|F(s)|\le \sum_n |a_n| n^{-c}$ on $\Re(s)=c$ thus it is completely obvious

Comment: @reuns I agree, but a reference was requested.

Comment: only x^c/T? i was actually hoping over T^2... i'll have a look in your reference

Comment: @tomos you are correct; I was being inefficient.

Comment: no worries :) efficiency once appeared on the street where i live, then left.  the street stayed the same though.

Comment: @tomos I updated my answer per our above discussion.  This reference answers your question.  Maybe you could accept this answer?

Comment: sure. this bit is just to make the comment long enough.